# Customizing Multi-Touch Gestures (OS X)

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos

Is it possible to create custom multi-touch gestures for OS X? I know you can now make up your own gestures through the System Preferences but my question is if it's possible for the gesture to perform an action that isn't listed in the possible Trackpad options in the OS default. For example, let's say I want to close an application by swiping with three fingers or something along those lines.

I understand that this would most likely be an outside application that would need to be written but I'm just trying to get an idea of where to start to read about this (the functions in Objective C to look at, etc.).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are you talking about gestures for any OS X application or just for a custom-built application? If you're developing an application it is certainly possible to support custom gestures; see here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/EventOverview/HandlingTouchEvents/HandlingTouchEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH13-SW1

Comment: OS X Application. Thanks for the link. That's perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, override touchesBegan and write your own custom code for interpreting the corresponding touch events.